# When send push notification getting error of "mismatch sender id"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When send push notification message then I am getting

> issue "MismatchSenderId"

I create new project and generate browser key without any referrer. In sender id I used `"Project Number: 70171220582"` and in Registration Id used device id and in Application Id Used API key which is generated. I also get response, but in stream reader I got `"Error=MisMatch SenderId"` message.

My code is here:

```
public void SendNotification(string data, HttpPostedFileBase CategoryCoverImage)
         {

             string RegId = "APA91bEvbPScQpHIwbIrOU5QPzFEEt6F7Ezrs5Cb7pG7pQBsEzuiv77S85F8WF6F2otHS8n8DXyuJrs-MQSpFMyx-07WOnMZKvzM3TkQZUdMQF";
             string ApplicationID = "AIzaSyBEXjdogpXXXXXXXXjvpOopU320";
             string SENDER_ID = "70171220582";
             var value = "Lokesh"; //message text box

             WebRequest tRequest;
       tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
       tRequest.Method = "post";
             tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
             tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", ApplicationID)); tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
             //Data post to the Server
             string postData =
         "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
          + value + "&file=" + CategoryCoverImage + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() +
          "&registration_id=" + RegId + "";

             Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
             tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
             Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
             dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
             dataStream.Close();
             WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse(); dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
             StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
             String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();  //Get response from GCM server  
             //label_Result.Text = sResponseFromServer; //Assigning GCM response to Label text
             tReader.Close(); dataStream.Close();
             tResponse.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your Key for server apps. It should be like below.

[image]

Reference:http://forum.shephertz.com/?qa=2754/push-notification-android-errorcode-mismatchsenderid

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: your image is not showing.. but i got api key from both (server and browser) with different projects I tried but i am getting same error.

Comment: No. No IP allowed. I checked from both with IP or Without IP but getting same error.

Comment: Then try it with Any IP allowed. as per my answer